# Storing and displaying multiple query string in arraylist using session variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, arraylist, session-variables

I have a webform with a grid of products. When you click on the product, it takes you to a page showing the individual product with a "add to cart" button. What I want to do is when i click the "add to cart" button, the session stores the query string of the productId in an array list every time a user clicks the "add to cart" button. I am able to store it in the session variable but when I want to display all of the query string, only the most recent one shows. Thanks in advance.

Here is the following code for the "add to cart" button:

```html
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string productId;

        ArrayList arProduct = new ArrayList();

        if (Request.QueryString.Get("ProductId") != null)
        {
            productId = Request.QueryString.Get("ProductId");
            arProduct.Add(productId);
        }

        Session["Cart"] = arProduct;
        Response.Redirect("Cart.aspx");
    }
```

Here is the following code for the page load of Cart.aspx:

```html
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["Cart"] != null)
        {
            lblProducts.Text = "Here are your products: " + "<ul>";
            ArrayList alProduct = new ArrayList();
            alProduct = (ArrayList)Session["Cart"];
            foreach (string item in alProduct)
            {
                lblProducts.Text +=  "<li>" + item + "</li>";
            }
            lblProducts.Text += "</ul>";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click 'add' you create a new `arProduct` and put it in `Session["Cart"]` every time. Thus a previous add would be overwritten. You need to reuse the `Session['Cart']` in the add event handler.

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string productId;

    ArrayList arProduct = Session['Cart'] as ArrayList;
    if(arProduct == null)
    {
        arProduct = new ArrayList();
        Session['Cart'] = arProduct;
    }

    if (Request.QueryString.Get("ProductId") != null)
    {
        productId = Request.QueryString.Get("ProductId");
        arProduct.Add(productId);
    }

    Session["Cart"] = arProduct;
    Response.Redirect("Cart.aspx");
}
```

Edit:

And for what it's worth, i would place the code for the arProduct into a property. And use that inside the `btnAdd_Click` handler and page load

Comment: That makes so much sense. Thanks for clearing this up for me @Dbuggy